# Javascript nested/higher-order function problem

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm confused about this nested function calling itself in another function. Take a look at these:

```
function countBy(items, groupName) {
  let counts = [];
  for (let item of items) {
    let name = groupName(item);
    let known = counts.findIndex(c => c.name == name);
    if (known == -1) {
      counts.push({name, count: 1});
    } else {
      counts[known].count++;
    }
  }
  return counts;
}
```

```
function characterScript(code) {
  for (let script of SCRIPTS) {
    if (script.ranges.some(([from, to]) => {
      return code >= from && code < to;
    })) {
      return script;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Those two function set the next one up, which is only confusing me at a single point:

```
function textScripts(text) {
  let scripts = countBy(text, char => {
    let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
    return script ? script.name : "none";
  })
return scripts;
}
```

When it says,
characterScript(**char**.codePointAt(0));
no matter how much I look at the countBy function, or the characterScript function, I can't understand how passing the **char** function into that position equals what you want it to be, which is a single item in a string or array.

console.log("Hello");

Comment: have you read the [documentation for String.codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)?

Comment: Yes, but char != a string.. char is a function. Somehow, it's returning as a single item of (text)

Comment: @jordan I don't think it's correct to think of `char` as a function.

The function that is going to become `groupName` is all of this code…

`char => {
    let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
    return script ? script.name : "none";
}`

…and when we call `groupName(item)` the `item` argument is what `char` is.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark & Dan. Mark.. I think I see what you're saying and am grasping it. What you're saying is, in the countBy function, it loops over items (for item of items), and each time it loops, it calls groupName(item). So, char isn't a function, it's actually the variable in an unnamed function. It's still really hard to wrap my head around, but I think I can get it from here with your answer.